# How to carry over pick list values from old Opportunity to new one?

Tags: apex, workflow, visual-workflow, process-builder, trigger

I have a workflow and Process builder that creates a New Opportunity. In that new opportunity I'd like to carry over 2 custom pick list fields data from the old opportunity. Is that possible using workflows or process builder??

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your setup but if you are creating the new opportunity from the closed opportunity in the Process Builder, you can set the picklist or any editable field to the value from the existing object. Just click on the pencil icon to change the mode to value and select the matching field.[image]

Comment: If you are using the process builder to create a new record, you can set the fields at that point, so if a record was generated manually the normal defaults would apply, but if it was automatically created by the process builder then those values would apply.

Comment: What object does the process builder fire from? If it is fired from the old opportunity, then those are the values it would use.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a few pictures of what your process builder looks like? It might help clear things up...

Comment: Here you go. The Picklist value is not on there since this is Activated.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm not sure where the concern is but you can definitely set a custom picklist field this way. It's the same as stage or any other picklist field but instead of typing a value you would select the value from the existing opportunity similar to your close date above. It will only effect the opportunity created by the winning opportunity. Best thing to do is create a quick example in your dev org that fires immediately so you can monitor the behavior.

Comment: I will do so thanks. But if I insert the picklist value in the above create process to be value A - how would the process use value B if the old opportunity had value B? By me selecting a value for a pick list on the create it will always be that value for every opportunity this process creates..correct?

Comment: You don't want to select a picklist value, you want to use the [Opportunity].custom_picklist__c just like your close date 365.